# Phpmyadmin configration

Tags: apache2, phpmyadmin

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 version and I install LAMP server , php and MYSql.
Install PhpmyAdmin

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

I insert line in  /etc/apache2/apache2.conf by using:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Insert line in "# Include the virtual host configurations:"

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

When I restart apache2 by using:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

This give me error:

```
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

... waiting apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName

Kindly help me to solve this problem?

Comment: How did you install apache2 and phpmyadmin? With apt-get install apache2 and apt-get install phpmyadmin?

Comment: I follow the following link to install apache2 [1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)

Comment: what happens when you open http ://localhost/phpmyadmin without adding the line in apache.conf?

Comment: Not Found
The requested URL /phpmyadmin was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Not: Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache2.conf

Just delete the 2 and it should work.

Comment: Now when I edit it save file option disable and I can't save it. Why? How can I reach it?

Comment: Probably you forgot to open it with sudo: sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: Yes you right, I forget to open it with sudo.

Comment: If the answer is solving your problem now, pleas accept it by clicking the "accept tick" on the left side

Comment: The  problem is not completely solved .When I restart :sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart. It give error: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts

Comment: Well. Thats a other problem. You should ask a new question for that and post your apache2.conf, your ports.conf, and your vhost configuration files.

Comment: My phpmyadmin is working. But the form asking about User Name and password. I don't understand what userName and Password I use to Login?

Comment: It is the username and passwort you gave for mysql. Most likely username: root